# Add a string after 4 characters for each element of a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list which each element is an urls with an `<a>` tag.
I need to add `target="_blank"` after `<a>` and before `"href="` for each element of the list

```
list = ["<a href=\"url_1\">Title_1</a>", 
    "<a href=\"url_2\">Title_2</a>", 
    "<a href=\"url_3\">Title_3</a>", 
    "<a href=\"url_4\">Title_4</a>"]
```

Comment: `result = [ s.replace('<a href', '<a target="_blank" href') for s in list ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using a list comprehension along with `re.sub`:

```
output = [re.sub(r'^<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', i) for i in list]
print(output)

['<a target="_blank" href="url_1">Title_1</a>',
 '<a target="_blank" href="url_2">Title_2</a>',
 '<a target="_blank" href="url_3">Title_3</a>',
 '<a target="_blank" href="url_4">Title_4</a>']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it without regex. An alternative to @Tim Biegeleisen solution. Explanation in code comments:

```
list = ["<a href=\"url_1\">Title_1</a>",
    "<a href=\"url_2\">Title_2</a>",
    "<a href=\"url_3\">Title_3</a>",
    "<a href=\"url_4\">Title_4</a>"]

new_list = []
# for each html string in the list
for html in list:
    # Create a new string concatenating the first 4 characters of html with  target="_blank"  and the remainder of html string
    s = html[:3] + 'target="_blank" ' + html[3:]
    new_list.append(s)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [`map`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function to perform the `target` addition:

```
inlist = ["<a href=\"url_1\">Title_1</a>", 
    "<a href=\"url_2\">Title_2</a>", 
    "<a href=\"url_3\">Title_3</a>", 
    "<a href=\"url_4\">Title_4</a>"]

newList = list(map(lambda elem: elem.replace('<a', '<a target="blank"'), inlist))
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
['<a target="blank" href="url_1">Title_1</a>', '<a target="blank" href="url_2">Title_2</a>', '<a target="blank" href="url_3">Title_3</a>', '<a target="blank" href="url_4">Title_4</a>']
```

**Note**: Do not use `list` as variable name because it's a reserved Python keyword.